# jquery-datatables-rails TableTools buttons not working in Rails4 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, datatables, tabletools

I have put the swf files into my public folder (under public/swf/)
The JS in question is this:

```
$("#leave_requests").dataTable({
  "aaSorting": [],
  "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
  "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
  "oTableTools": {
      "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
  }
});
```

I can see in the logs that the swf file is being found (most of the time), I am getting intermittent 304s amongst the 200s:

```
2014-07-24T09:30:58.331085+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" host=demo.leaverequest.co.nz request_id=d217e1d2-a995-4b35-8db2-80dae532dd37 fwd="101.98.148.9" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=1 status=304 bytes=1152
```

In the view, I can see the buttons, but clicking them is doing nothing (except print, but that is not handled by the swf control).

Edit - I can also see the loading of the relevant dataTables and tableTools js:

```
jquery.dataTables.js?body=1
/assets/dataTables
GET 304
Not Modified
jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.js?body=1
/assets/dataTables/bootstrap/3
GET 304
Not Modified
dataTables.tableTools.js?body=1
/assets/dataTables/extras
GET 304
Not Modified
```

Updated Edit:
If you are using jquery-datatables-rails you DO NOT need to include ZeroClipboard separately.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious - but did you include the tabletools js file? (https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js)
I don't think the file-path is your problem, 304s shouldn't matter since that just means not modified which is ok.

Comment: Good point, but they are there - updated the post with the relevant files.

Comment: Shouldn't it work without explicitly copying the swf files in your public directory? Having similar issue about not finding these files now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found out what was killing this, many thanks to Birgit Martinelle! Your prompt got me to really look at the js files.

I am using the jquery-datatables-rails gem and it was including the ZeroClipboard.js content inside the dataTables.TableTools.js

Based on what I had read on the dataTables.net site I was ALSO including ZeroClipboard separately, removing this, everything worked.

I have updated the question as well with some more specific details